# Find every 3-regular graph with order n and size 2n-3.

Tags: graph-theory

Find every $3$-regular graph with order $n$ and size $2n-3$.

Explain how you know that you found all of them.

It's hard for me to even come up with a 3-regular graph (other than k4)

Any hints or help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Use the Handshaking Lemma to deduce that $n=6$. So let $v_1,\ldots,v_6$ be six vertices in such a graph, and without loss of generality suppose $v_1$ is adjacent to $v_2,v_3$ and $v_4$. So now you just need to figure out the possible ways of drawing the remaining $6$ edges to get a $3$-regular graph, and then decide which ones are isomorphic.

Comment: A picture would definitely help. I've concluded that p is at least 3

Comment: @MichaelCera What's $p$?

Comment: Sorry, p or n is the number of vertices.

Comment: I got that if make a k(1,3) graph and add two vertices, I can have a graph that satisfies the above conditions. I don't know if this generalizes to multiples of 6 then or if there more than one isomorphic classes with 3regular graphs with 6 vertices and 9 edges.

Comment: @MichaelCera $n$ (or $p$) must be exactly $6$, by the Handshaking Lemma (the result that $2|E(G)|=\sum_{v\in V(G)}\deg(v)$).

Comment: Ok, I can see that the sum of the degrees must be divisible by 3(obviously). I can't seem to come up with a graph with degree sequence 22233 with 6 edges other than the one I spoke about.